# Netbeans 11.3 Java - JPanel design tab is frozen with just text saying "Loading..."

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I am trying to write a plugin for the Universal Gcode Sender (https://winder.github.io/ugs_website/), but when I try to create a JPanel in any directory except my module's main project directory and try to use the Design tab, it just shows the text "Loading..." and I can't do anything in the Design tab. This also happens when I create a new Netbeans Project and try to make a JPanel there.

I don't think this is because of an issue with UGS, rather a Netbeans issue or something.

I literally haven't been able to write any code because the first thing I need to do is make sure I can use the Design tab. Netbeans is entirely stock, I haven't changed anything to cause this.

I have tried multiple re installations of Netbeans and various other solutions. Nothing has worked.

I appreciate any help you can give. If I am missing any important info please tell me and I will supply it.

Comment: *"I literally haven't been able to write any code because the first thing I need to do is make sure I can use the Design tab."* Learn Java layouts, not IDEs.

Comment: Please provide the steps how you create the JPanel form in Netbeans.

Comment: @jjazzboss 
1. Navigate to directory in the "Projects" tab.
2. Right click on directory.
3. New --> JPanel Form
4. Name it and click finish.

Comment: Looks like a Netbeans issue but can't reproduce it. What NB version? OS? Also search "clean Netbeans cache and user directory" to ensure a fresh Netbeans restart.

Comment: @jazzboss I just cleared my cache and reinstalled. Nothing changed. I'm running the latest Netbeans 11.3 version with Windows 10. Also I really appreciate the help!